# I want to make sure I added icons correctly in X-Code4.5

Tags: xcode, icons, xcode4.5

I am developing an iphone only app in X-Code 4.5 and I am in the process of adding in my icons. I was not able to find specific instructions for adding in icon files specifically using X-Code 4.5 so I followed [these instructions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) which call for editing the info.plist which I am assuming is the "info" tab when view the target. Is that correct?

I attached a screenshot of the seven icons I included in the info/plist under icon Files. Please let me know if I did it correctly.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> editing the info.plist which I am assuming is the "info" tab when view the target. Is that correct?

Yes, it is.

The easiest way to verify that you added the icons correctly, is to run the app on your device or in the simulator. If the icon shows app (instead of the default white icon) it worked.

That being said, your config looks fine to me.

Comment: I tested it on the simulator on all devices and the icons seem to work. Thanks!